# Determine the specific value of the division of two factorial series

Tags: limits, summation, power-series, taylor-expansion, euler-maclaurin

I want to find a specific range of $\alpha$ formula as follows.

$$\alpha =\frac{1+\frac{{{x}^{2}}}{3!}+\frac{{{x}^{4}}}{5!}++\cdots+{\frac {x^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}}}{1+\frac{{{x}^{2}}}{2!}+\frac{{{x}^{4}}}{4!}+\cdots +{\frac {x^{2n}}{(2n)!}}}$$

We know that 0 < $\alpha$ < 1. But, I want to narrow this range or make it more specific value as much as possible?
If it is possible, could you please suggest me some ways to do it without depending on the variable $n$ ($n\to \infty $)?

Comment: @metamorphy, can you suggest an answer without depending on the 'n' variable (consider $n\to \infty $)?

Comment: Numerically, it seems that $$\frac{{\tanh x}}{{x}} \le \alpha (x) \le \frac{{x^2  + 6}}{{3x^2  + 6}} \le 1.$$

Comment: Yes, I want to find a minimum value (a constant) of this formula. Is it possible? How could we derive it? can you suggest?

Comment: It seems that for any fixed $x$ it is a monotonically decreasing sequence with respect to $n$. I do not have a proof though.